# Write transparent HTTP Proxy script in PHP

Tags: php, http, proxy

Is there an easy forwarding/transparent php proxy script that I can host on my web server? These are my conditions:

1. I'm using free web hosting, so I have pretty much no control over my machine. Otherwise I could use Perl's HTTP::Proxy module. This means no root password. It does run php though.
2. I already have a server running on port 80. What I mean is I would like to put a php script as index.php on my server that will forward all requests.
3. I don't want a script like PHProxy or Glype where I go to the site, then enter a URL. I want a server so I can enter proxy.example.com:80 in Firefox's or IE's or whatever's proxy settings and it will forward all requests to the server.
4. Preferably (though not fatal if not possible) I would like for it to pass on the USER_AGENT environmental variable (That's the browser) instead of setting itself to be the USER_AGENT
5. I can't start a new Daemon. My server won't allow it.

Is there a script that will do this? If so, which?

Comment: Does your host have cURL support compiled into their php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I'm fairly sure this is not possible on shared hosting. It will fail your condition number 3. This needs support on web server level (e.g. using Apache's `mod_proxy`)

For this to work, you would have to set up the remote server to be able to deal with proxied requests. No sane web server will offer that possibility.

Comment: +1 Apache usually tells "Connection attempts using mod_proxy" in its log. I suppose it happens when someone tries to use the server as a proxy. That is, passing absolute URI (which is intended for use with proxies) instead of a path to a resource.